# How do I retrieve PR_RULE_ACTIONS via PowerShell and the EWS Managed API?

Tags: powershell, delegates, exchangewebservices, mapi, ews-managed-api

I have need of retrieving and inspecting the delegate forwarding rule (the built-in delegate commands in EWS being inadequate for my needs since they choke on groups being used as delegates).

I am able to successfully locate the rule created by "`Schedule+ EMS Interface`".  However, I am unable to retrieve `PR_RULE_ACTIONS`.  Turning on tracing.

I see that the PidTagRuleMsgProvider property is getting returned just fine, but `PR_RULE_ACTIONS` never does.

I suspect that I am using the wrong MAPI property type in the propertyset definition, but I've gone through everything listed at  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchangewebservices.mapipropertytypetype(v=exchg.140).aspx .  Any clues?

Here is the relevant snippet of code:

```
# Setup Basic EWS Properties for Message Search - Used to locate Hidden Forwarding Rule
$searchFilterForwardRule         = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+ContainsSubstring([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemSchema]::ItemClass, "IPM.Rule", [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ContainmentMode]::Prefixed, [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ComparisonMode]::Exact)
$itemViewForwardRule             = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemView(30, 0, [Microsoft.Exchange.Webservices.Data.OffsetBasePoint]::Beginning)
$itemViewForwardRule.PropertySet = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PropertySet([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.BasePropertySet]::FirstClassProperties, [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemSchema]::ItemClass, [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemSchema]::Subject)
$itemViewForwardRule.Traversal   = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemTraversal]::Associated

# Properties for Hidden Delegate Forwarding Rule
$PID_TAG_RULE_MSG_PROVIDER    = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x65EB,[Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MapiPropertyType]::String)
$PID_TAG_RULE_ACTIONS     =  New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x6680,[Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MapiPropertyType]::Binary)

# Property Set for Delegate Forward Rule
$propertySetForwardRule = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PropertySet([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.BasePropertySet]::FirstClassProperties, $PID_TAG_RULE_MSG_PROVIDER)

$forwardRuleExists = $false

$findResults = $service.FindItems([Microsoft.Exchange.Webservices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Inbox, $searchFilterForwardRule, $itemViewForwardRule)


If ($findResults.TotalCount -lt 1) {
Write-Error "Failed to find rule" "Error"
} Else {
Foreach ($item in $findResults.Items) {

    $item.Load($propertySetForwardRule)


    If ($item.ExtendedProperties.Count -ge 1) {

        If ($item.ExtendedProperties[0].Value -eq "Schedule+ EMS Interface") {
            $forwardRuleExists = $true
            write-host "Delegate forwarding rule found." -ForegroundColor Cyan

            $propertySetForwardRule.Add($PID_TAG_RULE_ACTIONS)
            $item.Load($propertySetForwardRule)

            Write-Host "Attempting to retrieve x6680 PR_RULE_ACTIONS (PidTagRuleActions)" -ForegroundColor Cyan
            $PR_RULE_ACTIONS = $null 
                if($Item.TryGetProperty($Pid_Tag_Rule_Actions,[ref]$PR_RULE_ACTIONS)){  

                    return $PR_RULE_ACTIONS
                } # endif
              else {write-host "TryGetProperty for PR_RULE_ACTIONS failed!" -ForegroundColor Red 
                } # endelse


        } # End If - Correct Message 

    } # End If - Has Extended Properties
} # End ForEach            
} # End If - Message Count
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glen Scales was able to set me on the right path. It turns out that PR_RULE_ACTIONS is not exposed via EWS, but the same data exposed via an attribute called PR_EXTENDED_RULE_ACTIONS. Now I'm happily slinging code to parse the binary blob.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee218391(v=EXCHG.80).aspx

Comment: Well, it is exposed in the Exchange 2013 Exchange Online environment, but not by our on-premise Exchange 2010 environment. Still trying to figure out why....

Answer (score 0):

The property tag for `PR_RULE_ACTIONS` is `0x668000FE`. You can see it (and the property data) in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) - go to the Inbox folder, click IMAPIFolder button, go to the PR_RULES_TABLE tab, select the rule, double click on the PR_RULE_ACTIONS property.

Note that `PT_ACTIONS` MAPI type (`0x000FE`) is only accessing in Extended MAPI, I don't think EWS will be able to return it.

Comment: Yes, I had found that property type in the docs.  However, when specifying a MAPI property type in the EWS Managed API, I can only specify one of the values listed in the URL I had previously referenced (Binary, Integer, String, StringArray, etc.).